C# Testing framework with runtime configurable params?
I have a lot of fixture libraries in c# and now want to leverage those for integration tests on a product. I have the most experience using xunit.
The aim of this question is that there are multiple transports to configure this product over, but the method is the same so communicating is abstracted to an interface that concrete transports implement for this library to communicate to the physical device.
The parametrisation is required to:

Pass in the transport object for this test

The aim of this is to write one test and then parametrise what transport we are testing over


Devices address on the bus

My current approach would be to write the test and then use inline data to set what the transport is
[Theory]
[InLineData(new TransportA())]
[InLineData(new TransportB())]
public void Test(ITransport transport)
{
    // Test
}

However, I am more so looking for completely separate namespaces so that there is a TransportA.TestA and TransportB.TestA where TestA is the same code. I initially thought of making this an abstract class and then Transports have a concrete test class but was unsure how xunit would handle test attributes that it can't run?
On top of the transport issue is the bus address that I can't solve. For this run, it might be testing address 0, but next we might be testing address 1? Is this possible for a runtime configuration parameter? My solution here was having a configuration json that tests would load with these sorts of runtime params.
